# Constructor is not working properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need help building a constructor that would initialized the respective data when instantiated within
the main().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Entity{
      public:
          int x, int y, char icon; };

int main(){
Entity pData;
pData.x=4; pData.y=3, pData.icon='1';
cout<<pData.x<<'\n'\; cout<<pData.y<<'\n'\; cout<<pData.icon<<\'n'\;
}
```

I included an example of what i need only... there no need to include all the program. Anyways I need the constructor to initialized the data in the main as soon as the instance(pData) of Entity is created: I know the constructor has to be something like

```
Entity::Entity(int x, int y, char icon){};
```

and once instantiated in the main it would be something like

```
Entity pData{3,4,'1'};
```

but obviously this isn't working for me

oh by the way I need a constructor because that's what the assignment is asking in the first place here you go copied right off from the doc file

"write a parameterized constructor for the Entity class that sets x, y, and icon, and use it when creating the instance"

Comment: Is there something in the {} of your constructor? Or it this the whole thing?

Comment: well that's what I don't fully get right.. do i need something inside the {} ? My book does a bad job at explaining this

Comment: See below for constructor examples (and why you don´t need one in this case). Generally speaking, a constructor is executed when a object is created. It *can* give the variables some initial values (fixed values or some parameter values or...), but it can do anything else too. It´s like a normal method, just called automatically. If it is an emptry method, it won´t do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually u have not defined constructor for your class `Entity`(But compiler have defined it for you but it only allocate memory for member variable of `Entity`).

`class Entity {
    public:
    int x,y;
    char icon;
     Entity(int _x, int _y,char _icon)
     {
          x=_x;
          y=_y
          icon=_icon;
     }
     };`

```
 int main()
 {
   Entity obj(4,3,'I');
   return 0;
 }
```

`

Comment: Aww, I see the constructor is defined inside the public part of the class. AWESOME!!!this did the trick for me. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
Entity::Entity(int a, int b, char c)
{
  x = a;
  y = b;
  icon = c;
};
```

Define your constructor like this...

And call it like:-

```
Entity pData( 1,2,'a');
```

Comment: and you would put that block of code (definition) right after your class definition right?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a constructor because your class is an aggregate. This would work (after fixing some typos)

```
class Entity
{
 public:
  int x, y; 
  char icon; 
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using std::cout;

  Entity pData{3,4,'1'};

  cout << pData.x <<'\n'; 
  cout << pData.y <<'\n'; 
  cout << pData.icon <<'\n';
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but the instructions for the assignment read "write a parameterized constructor for the Entity class that sets x,y, and icon, and use it when creating the instance.

Comment: @Ardy Then why didn't you put that information in your question?

Comment: Well sorry, I took like 10 mins to write the question then went afk for a sec and came back o post without realizing someone (my kid brother) deleted a chunk of info so I rewrote again and forgot to add that. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can for example define a constructor the following way

```
class Entity{
      public:
          Entity( int x, int y, char icon ) : x( x ), y( y ), icon( icon ) {}
          int x, int y, char icon; 
};
```

And use it like

```
Entity pData( 4, 3,'1' );
```

or

```
Entity pData { 4, 3,'1' };
```

or

```
Entity pData = { 4, 3,'1' };
```

Take into account that for your original class definition you could write

```
Entity pData = { 4, 3,'1' };
```

without defining explicitly a constructor.